# Error in Creating JSON object

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm getting an  JSON array  as a string value and I need to create a JSON object using that. array code is like this.

```
{"eventsList" : [
    "requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c"
    events:[
        {
            "eventType" : "receiveLocation_Event", 
            "externalId" : "973af2f8-820b-457b-89c2", 
            "description" : "Test Event",
            "whenOccurred" : "06-Aug-2013 07.15.01.0 AM",
            "partnerId" : "cecdbd94-ac60-4db0-b7f2", 
            "tagsAndValues" : { 
                 "locationAccuracy" : "10",
                 "attr2" : "value2"
            },
            "count" : "2" 
         },
         {
            "eventType" : "SEND_SMS_sendSmsEvent",
            "externalId" : "45af4f8-87-4f42b-832abc",
            "description" : "Another Test Event",
            "whenOccurred" : "06-Aug-2013 08.16.01.0 AM",
            "partnerId" : "cecdbd94-ac60-4db0-b7f2",
            "tagsAndValues" : { 
                  "messageLength" : "135",
                  "attrX" : "valueX"
             }, 
            "count" : "1" 
          }
    ]

 }

]
}
```

i try to create an JSON object using folowing code line

```
SONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
```

I'm getting an error when i run this.

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at character 35
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:413)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:143)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:351)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:206)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:420)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: String is not in the form to be converted into json

Comment: Remove node after node from the JSON until it is valid. Then you´ll find what´s wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes.

- After `[` a list of comma-separated values is expected, but you have a colon after `"requestId"`. You probably meant for the `[` on line 1 to be a `{`.
- Given the last issue, you probably want a comma after `"82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c"`

If you drop your text into an online JSON formatter and validator, such as [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) it will point out all your errors.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:
...
"requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c"
    events:...

You forgot some punctuation:
...
"requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c",
 "events":......

Use this instead this is JSON syntax. All keys are strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the String should be;

```
{"eventsList" : [
    {"requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c"},
   { "events":[
        {
            "eventType" : "receiveLocation_Event", 
            "externalId" : "973af2f8-820b-457b-89c2", 
            "description" : "Test Event",
            "whenOccurred" : "06-Aug-2013 07.15.01.0 AM",
            "partnerId" : "cecdbd94-ac60-4db0-b7f2", 
            "tagsAndValues" : { 
                 "locationAccuracy" : "10",
                 "attr2" : "value2"
            },
            "count" : "2" 
         },
         {
            "eventType" : "SEND_SMS_sendSmsEvent",
            "externalId" : "45af4f8-87-4f42b-832abc",
            "description" : "Another Test Event",
            "whenOccurred" : "06-Aug-2013 08.16.01.0 AM",
            "partnerId" : "cecdbd94-ac60-4db0-b7f2",
            "tagsAndValues" : { 
                  "messageLength" : "135",
                  "attrX" : "valueX"
             }, 
            "count" : "1" 
          }
    ]

 }
 ]
}
```

the requestId and event must be like this: `{"requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c"},
   { "events":`
And also there must be closing } after closing the inner JSONArray ]